# How to get part of an Element in Android using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to find a way to get the last part of a Element and set it to a textView 
Here is my code for getting the element and setting it to a textView.

```
Element burnabyStatus = doc.getElementsByClass("main-campus-status").first();
String b_status = burnabyStatus.text();
TextView tv_b_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b_status);
tv_b_status.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
tv_b_status.setText(b_status);
```

As of now burnabyStatus.text() is equal to "Burnaby Campus Open" but I want my textView to just show "Open" or "Closed" for when it changes on the website. 
Here is the website from where I am getting the information from [here](http://www.sfu.ca/security/sfuroadconditions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the website, The word you need "Open" is in a "h1" child element under the "main-campus-status" div element, hence what you need to do is get the text of the "h1" element, and you can do it like this:

```
Element burnabyStatus = doc.getElementsByClass("main-campus-status").first();
Elements h1 = burnabyStatus.select("h1");
burnabyStatus = h1.get(0);
String b_status = burnabyStatus.text();
TextView tv_b_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b_status);
tv_b_status.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
tv_b_status.setText(b_status);
```

The lines I've added are:

```
Elements h1 = burnabyStatus.select("h1");
burnabyStatus = h1.get(0);
```

Which selects all h1 elements under the "main-campus-status" div which when you call "text()" will only get you "Open" or "Closed".